# Hi, i have a problem with a For loop and i de-bugged it but cannot see the reason for the result i'm given

Tags: java

Hi the problem i have with this code when i debug it, is the the index <===is giving me null, i cannot figure out why. When i list all members in another method it is working fine. emailEntered is passing in what i enter it's just member is null. I have gone through everything i could find on the internet related to the problem. I just cant see it, i'm just a student so take it easy on me if it is a simple problem i just can't see. Thank you.

```
 public class GymAPI {
private ArrayList<Member> members;
private ArrayList<Trainer> trainers;
private Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


public GymAPI() {
    this.members = new ArrayList<Member>();
    trainers = new ArrayList<Trainer>();


}

 public Member searchMembersByEmail (String emailEntered) {
    if (members != null) {
        if (members.contains(emailEntered)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
                if (emailEntered.equals(members.get(i).getEmail())) {
                    return members.get(i);
                }
            }

        }
    }return null;
}


switch (option){
            case 1:
                        gymAPI.addMember(member);
                        break;
            case 2:     listMembers();
                        break;
            case 3:     System.out.print("Enter the email: ");
                        String EmailEntered = input.next();
                        System.out.println("" + gymAPI.searchMembersByEmail(EmailEntered));
                break;
            default:    System.out.println("Invalid option entered: " + option);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't provided a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - where is `members` defined?

Comment: ArrayList<Member>members = new ArrayList<>(); is at the top in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`members` will never contain `emailEntered` as String is a different class from Member. Therefore the first if condition is useless.

```
public Member searchMembersByEmail(String emailEntered) {
    if (members != null) {
        for (Member m : members) {
            if (m == null) continue;

            if (emailEntered.equals(m.getEmail())) 
                return m;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: i have tried it this way aswell but keeps giving back null

Comment: members.get(i) is giving null

Comment: That's not possible as `members.get(i).getEmail()` would throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thats what it is doing but i can't figure out why?

Comment: You should check that the list actually contains a `Member` with the entered email. Try adding some debug lines to check if it's the case.

Comment: When i debug it, it shows that members.get(i)is null, without debug it thous the NPE

Comment: When i list the member in switch case 2, it displays all members i entered

Comment: i enter the member and then i list to make sure it in the list, then i search with the code but NPE

Comment: i have tried it this way with the for each loop too but gives me back back member is null and it's throwing the NPE

Comment: You must have some `null` values inside your list then. You can either avoid them to be added or check that in the loop. I've updated the answer.